# drone power distribution board on a perf board

Tags: power-supply, pcb, embedded, drone

I have seen some PCBs dedicated to being a power distribution board but the drone that I have has some connections for an in-frame power distribution board.

only thing is that it may be difficult to make good connections so I was thinking of making my own on a perfboard and strapping it on the frame.

is it possible to make a simple PD board on a perf board? i know the more complex PD boards have voltage regulators and capacitors but how important are those exactly?

from the way that my drone frame implied that the PD board can be on the frame itself tells me that all the power distribution can be done through simple wires. my understanding is that the PD board just allows connections in parallel to be made from the motors to the battery.

so that is something i can set up on a dedicated perf board (and perhaps add regulators and capacitors as needed) but i am not sure if it is a good idea since i haven't seen it very often and 30 amps from the battery may not be suitable for a prototyping/perfboard

**edit: [this](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/284005585210?hash=item42200d513a:g:4-IAAOSwENVfWIUH) is the frame and motors i am referring to. [this](https://www.amazon.ca/Zeee-Connector-Airplane-Helicopter-Quadcopter/dp/B08JC5BWN1/ref=pd_cart_rp_1_1/138-2900486-1289132?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B08JC5BWN1&pd_rd_r=7d7f0a80-e96f-4b1b-957e-a7bf260ec6d8&pd_rd_w=ZHOIb&pd_rd_wg=qoFnj&pf_rd_p=da7def51-dd16-4a38-bc55-2a35dc2953bb&pf_rd_r=FC1TDTBQDN98QH5BZ8PW&psc=1&refRID=FC1TDTBQDN98QH5BZ8PW) is the battery that powers the motors and their ESCs.**

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to make a simple PD board on a perf board?

Yes, perf boards on their own are made to do things like this, exactly.

> i know the more complex PD boards have voltage regulators and capacitors but how important are those exactly?

These are extremely important (and most likely essential). If voltage regulator and capacitors are not in the board, then what is on the board?

To give a more detailed answer, we'd have to know the specs of what exactly you are trying to do. Current doesn't matter to perf boards because no current flows through perf boards. They are just insulators with holes drilled in them to hold components connected by wires. You'd need the wires and connectors specced for 30 A and the perf board specced for voltage (which they usually are for 100s if not 1000s of volts).

Comment: thanks! i have added the specs of the products that i am talking about. the battery is 11.1 V 5500mAh 50C LiPo and the ESCs that use that power can take up to 40A burst but the working current is 30A. hopefully that helps. basically i want to know if its a bad idea to have power distribution on the frame itself without any additional regulators/capacitors.